# C library for graphs

Tags: c, ruby, directed-acyclic-graphs, ruby-c-extension

Is there a good C library for graph theoretic manipulations? I particularly need to calculate the [strongly connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) of a directed graph. I have implemented [Tarjan's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) in Ruby as follows:

```
    def strongly_connected_components graph
        @index, @stack, @indice, @lowlink, @scc = 0, [], {}, {}, []
        @graph = graph
        vertices(@graph).each{|v| strong_connect(v) unless @indice[v]}
        @scc
    end
    def strong_connect v
        @indice[v] = @index
        @lowlink[v] = @index
        @index += 1
        @stack.push(v)
        @graph.each do |vv, w|
            next unless vv == v
            if !@indice[w]
                strong_connect(w)
                @lowlink[v] = [@lowlink[v], @lowlink[w]].min
            elsif @stack.include?(w)
                @lowlink[v] = [@lowlink[v], @indice[w]].min
            end
        end
        if @lowlink[v] == @indice[v]
            i = @stack.index(v)
            @scc.push(@stack[i..-1])
            @stack = @stack[0...i]
        end
    end
```

and it was working with small graphs, but as the graph grew big, it started to return "stack level too deep" errors due to recursive call of the method `strong_connect`. I guess I need a C library and access that from Ruby, in which the main program is written.

In addition to the library, any suggestion for using that in a Ruby library would be a help.

Comment: Does it need to be c?  I've been told the [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) is the way to go if you're ok with c++.

Comment: @Michael That's fine as long as it can be called from Ruby. I just am not familiar with extending Ruby using other languages. Do you have any idea how to call it from Ruby?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea.  I've barely used Ruby at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across the [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/documentation.html) library.  It is written in C and has wrappers for Ruby, Python and R.  For you, this means that you can enjoy the speed of C with the comfort of Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

[Ruby Graph Library (RGL)](http://rgl.rubyforge.org/rgl/index.html) (written in Ruby) is one option to consider.

Comment: Do you have any idea about the scalability of this library? Since I also implemented the same algorithm in Ruby, and had a problem, I am concerned that this library is also written in Ruby. It could be that there is a way to avoid the problems that I had. I don't know.

Comment: @sawa: I don't know about its scalability.

Answer (score 0):

**In C++ ther is [CXXGraph](https://github.com/ZigRazor/CXXGraph) Library**, that is an header-only library for graph manipulation and algorithms.